# Using promises in cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Here is some code that partially works and partially doesn't.
I tried keep(as much as possible) only the parts relevant to my question.
See my concerns after the code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define
("myCloudFunction", function(request, response)
 {
 var recordTypeArray,className,recordListQuery,resultDictionary;
 recordTypeArray = ["LT1","LT2","LT3","RT1","RT2","RT3"];
 resultDictionary = [];

 console.log("Trace-One");
 watchFunction(recordTypeArray,0,resultDictionary).then
 (function(resRcd) {
  console.log("Trace-Two");
  response.success(resultDictionary);
  });
 console.log("Trace-Three");

 });


function watchFunction(typeArray,typeNumber,resDico)
{
    var className,recordListQuery;
    className = "AA_".concat(typeArray[typeNumber]).concat("_ZZ");
    recordListQuery = new Parse.Query(className);

    return (recordListQuery.find().then
            (function(resRcd) {
             // Here some problemless code.
             if (typeNumber++==typeArray.length) return promise(function(){});
             return watchFunction(typeArray,typeNumber,resDico)
             })
            );
}
```

I am doing something wrong concerning the way I handle promises, but I don't know what.

I want to see **Trace-One**, then **watchFunction** do its job (*this part actually works fine*) an finally see **Trace-Two**, before performing **response.success**.

But what happens is I see **Trace-One**, then I see **Trace-Three**, then I can see in the log that watchFunction has done its job as it should. And I never see **Trace-Two**.
And as one could expect I get a message complaining that **success/error was not called**
So why am I not seeing **Trace-Two** and jumping to **Trace-Three**?
I presume I am not returning a promise from somewhere correctly.
I wish someone can point out where my mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `watchFunction` to perform several queries, one for each class name that can be derived from `typeArray`.  But if those queries succeed, `watchFunction` is guaranteed to crash by indexing `typeArray` out of bounds.  The function also drops the results, assigning them to a never-referenced dummy argument.

A simpler way to produce those several queries is to map each class name to a promise to query that class.  `Parse.Promise.when()` will run all of queries and be fulfilled with a (var arg) array of arrays containing the results.  (`Parse.Query.or()` ought to do the same, combining the results in a single array).

So, fix watchFunction:

```
// create a collection of promises to query each class indicated
// by type array, return a promise to run all of the promises
function watchFunction(typeArray) {
    var promises = [];
    for (i=0; i<typeArray.length; ++i) {
        var className = "AA_".concat(typeArray[i]).concat("_ZZ");
        var recordListQuery = new Parse.Query(className);
        promises.push(recordListQuery.find());
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}
```

The cloud function should also call response error, and can be cleaned up a little bit...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myCloudFunction", function(request, response) {

    var recordTypeArray = ["LT1","LT2","LT3","RT1","RT2","RT3"];
    console.log("Trace-One");

    watchFunction(recordTypeArray).then(function() {
       console.log("Trace-Two");
       response.success(arguments);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Trace-Two (error)");
        response.error(error);
    });
    console.log("Trace-Three");
});
```

You should expect to see Trace-One, Trace-Three, Trace-Two in the logs, since the "Trace-Two" logs happen after the queries finish.

Comment: Your sample code got me out of dirty waters, following the way you do I was able to make my code work. First sticking to what you do, then using what I understood from it to make what I did work. Your watchFunction has one trouble for my needs, it does not guarranty the order in which the promises in the array are fullfilled, for that reason I got random (possibily wrong) results. So I finally kept the recursive approach I use instead of the loop you use.